# MAC address string comparison fails

Tags: string, powershell, substring

I try to extract a computername from a txt file `$pcliste` using a string comparison to the MAC address of the local machine. the text file contains:

```
super-pc 00:15:5D:FF:0B:33
av-client4 00:15:5D:FF:0B:38
temp 00:15:5D:FF:0B:39
```

I use the following PowerShell code:

```
$macadresse = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select macaddress
$macadresse = $macadresse.macaddress

$pcnamen = Get-Content -Path $pcliste
$computername = "TEMP-NAME"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $pcnamen.Length; $i++) {
    $string =  $pcnamen[$i]
    if ($string -match $macadresse) {
        write "MAC found!"
        $index = $pcnamen[$i].IndexOf(" ")
        $computername = $pcnamen[$i].substring(0, $index)
    }
}
```

the MAC adress of my test VM is `00:15:5D:FF:0B:38`, but the string comparison in the loop remains false.

For testing I already put the MAC in a string variable instead of extracting it using the `Get-WmiObject`, and this works. 
I also tried to convert the extracted macadress to a string using `[string]$macadress`.

I assume it's some kind of datatype/objecttype problem that causes the `-match` to fail.

Comment: `$macadresse` is likely an array. So you may need to use `-in` / `-contains` rather than `-match` or loop through the array.

Comment: Since you're apparently reading lines with hostname and MAC address you may also want to split them, so you get a variable with just the MAC address (otherwise `-contains`/`-in` won't work): `$hostname, $string = $pcname[$i] -split '\s+'`.

Answer (score 1):

What about a hash table to put the MAC as key and pc name as value in.

```
$MyMACs = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration|Select -Expand MacAddress
$MyMACs

$PcHash = @{}
ForEach ($Row in (Get-Content '.\pcliste.txt')) {
  $PcHash.Add($Row.Split(' ')[1],$Row.Split(' ')[0])
}
ForEach($Mac in $MyMACs){
  IF ($PcHash[$Mac]){
    "Found {0} for MAC {1}" -f $PcHash[$Mac],$Mac 
  }
}
```

Or more basic

```
$MyMACs = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration|Select -Expand MacAddress
ForEach($Mac in $MyMACs){
   Select-String -Path '.\pcliste.txt' -Pattern $MAC|ForEach-Object{$_.Line}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify like this:

```
$string =  $pcnamen[$i] -split " "
if ($macadresse -contains $string[1]) {
```

you can simplify your code like this :

```
$pcnamen = import-csv $pcliste -Delimiter ' ' -Header Computer, Mac

Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | %{
$Mac=$_.macaddress
$pcnamen | where Mac -eq $Mac 
}
```